# MySQL - how to replace ORDER BY in a bit more complicated query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random, sql-order-by

For fetching records from a table I use this mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id as aid, a.data1 as adata1, a.data2 as adata2
    b.id as bid, b.data1 as bdata1, b.data2 as bdata2
FROM table AS a
JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) 
WHERE (a.data1=1 AND b.data1=1) AND ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) <100
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

This query fetching exactly the records which I need, but unfortunately because of `RAND()` is this query quite slow.

I've found some ways, how to avoid using `RAND()` function, for example [here](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/). But my problem is, that I still cannot find a way, how to replace `RAND()` function in this query.
In some simple query is not problem to replace `RAND()`, but I don't know, how to do that in the example above... because of more conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the RAND()?  This is pretty much a Cartesian join.  If you take out the "ORDER BY" what type of explain plan do you get?

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output?

Comment: How many rows does the table have? How many with `data1=1`? How many rows are returned, if you removed the `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using MySQL you can try with the following SQL queries that first gets a count from the table, then selects a random offset based on that count. It then prepares a statement so the calculated offset can be used and executes the statement.

```
SELECT @count := COUNT(*) FROM table AS a JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) WHERE (a.data1=1 AND b.data1=1) AND ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) <100;
SET @offset = CONVERT(FLOOR(RAND() * @count), SIGNED);
PREPARE mystatement FROM "SELECT 
                          a.id as aid, a.data1 as adata1, a.data2 as adata2
                          b.id as bid, b.data1 as bdata1, b.data2 as bdata2
                          FROM table AS a
                          JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) 
                          WHERE (a.data1=1 AND b.data1=1) AND ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) <100 LIMIT ?, 1";
EXECUTE mystatement USING @offset;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE mystatement;
```

On a large dataset should perform faster than `ORDER BY RAND()`, try and let me know ... ;-)

**EDIT**

The queries will not work used on phpmyadmin, so run them using the MySQL console or write a php script in which you have two option, the first one is let mysql do the work :

```
mysql_query('SELECT @count := COUNT(*) FROM table AS a JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) WHERE (a.data1=1 AND b.data1=1) AND ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) <100');
mysql_query('SET @offset = CONVERT(FLOOR(RAND() * @count), SIGNED)');
mysql_query('PREPARE mystatement FROM "SELECT 
                          a.id as aid, a.data1 as adata1, a.data2 as adata2
                          b.id as bid, b.data1 as bdata1, b.data2 as bdata2
                          FROM table AS a
                          JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) 
                          WHERE (a.data1=1 AND b.data1=1) AND ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) <100 LIMIT ?, 1"');
$res = mysql_query('EXECUTE mystatement USING @offset');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
print_r($row);
```

The second option that could be even more faster consist of doing a part of the work with MySQL and the other part with the programming language (in our case PHP) :

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS a JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) WHERE (a.data1=1 AND b.data1=1) AND ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) <100')");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$offset = rand(0, $row[0]-1);

$res = mysql_query("SELECT 
                              a.id as aid, a.data1 as adata1, a.data2 as adata2
                              b.id as bid, b.data1 as bdata1, b.data2 as bdata2
                              FROM table AS a
                              JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) 
                              WHERE (a.data1=1 AND b.data1=1) AND ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) <100 LIMIT $offset, 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Another alternative way to speed up the ORDER BY RAND() that I've found consist in a query like the following :

```
SELECT 
    a.id as aid, a.data1 as adata1, a.data2 as adata2
    b.id as bid, b.data1 as bdata1, b.data2 as bdata2
FROM table AS a
JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) 
WHERE (RAND() < (SELECT ((1/COUNT(*))*10) FROM table AS a JOIN table AS b ON ( a.id <> b.id ) ) )
 AND (a.data1=1 AND b.data1=1) AND ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) <100
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

Don't forget to update me about the result you get ;-) .

Comment: aleroot: thank you for your post. I tried to run this query into phpmyadmin and got this error message: `#1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (mystatement) given to EXECUTE` so, I've tried to remove the last two rows (starts with `EXECUTE` and `DEALLOCATE`) and got just `@count := COUNT(*) => `683066` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not use the query from phpmyadmin it will not work, execute from the command line utility (mysql) .

Comment: unfortunately the app is on the hosting and I cannot run the query from the command line. So, I have to find a way to run it - I will try to rewrite it into my PHP code.

Comment: @user984621 Yes, if you need to run it with a PHP script I wrote two snippets of code in my edited answer to help you ...

Comment: Thank you so much man! You probably solved my 2 nights-long nightmare! It's working, I tested it now for a few minutes and it's definitely faster than before. Now the query takes about 2 seconds in average. Currently I am using the 2nd PHP snippet and I am going to try the last SQL query, if it would be even faster yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very specific . . . how large are the tables?  What, exactly, is "quite slow"?  You are trying to find all pairs of records in your table, where data1 = 1 and the difference in ratings is less than 100.  In the following version, I moved all the conditions to the "ON" clause, so they are more clearly together:

```
SELECT a.id as aid, a.data1 as adata1, a.data2 as adata2
       b.id as bid, b.data1 as bdata1, b.data2 as bdata2
FROM table AS a join
     table AS b
     ON a.id <> b.id and
        a.data1 = b.data1 and
        a.data1 = 1 and b.data1 = 1 and
        ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) < 100
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

I also added the additional condition `a.data1 = b.data1`, because this helps the SQL engine recognize this as an equijoin, which should help join performance.

Assuming that data1 is selective (meaning that relatively few records have data1), then you should be able to speed this up with an index on (data1, id) or (data1, rating).

If you know that there is at least one match for every record (that is, every record has another record with a similar rating), the following variation should work better:

```
SELECT a.id as aid, a.data1 as adata1, a.data2 as adata2
       b.id as bid, b.data1 as bdata1, b.data2 as bdata2
FROM (select *
      from table AS a
      where a.data1 = 1
      order by rand()
      limit 1
     ) a join
     table AS b
     ON a.id <> b.id and
        a.data1 = b.data1 and
        a.data1 = 1 and b.data1 = 1 and
        ABS( a.rating - b.rating ) < 100
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

This first picks a random record, and then does the self-join.

This gives me the idea that you could take a different approach to this problem, as follows.  First calculate the ratings for the data you are looking at.  Then choose a random pair of rating where the difference is less than 100 and then find a random record that matches those.  With an index on data1 and rating, this approach might be the fastest.

Comment: @Gordong: thanks for your message. I am gonna try it. About your questions - the table has approx 11.000 records, "quite slow" is 6 seconds, without `ORDER BY RAND()` 0.5 seconds. I am trying to find 2 unique records from the same category where the rating difference is less than 100.

Answer (score 0):

If you're O.K. with a somewhat less uniform distribution over the problem space, you could try:

```
SELECT a.id as aid, a.data1 as adata1, a.data2 as adata2
       b.id as bid, b.data1 as bdata1, b.data2 as bdata2
  FROM ( SELECT *
           FROM table
          WHERE data1 = 1
          ORDER
             BY RAND()
          LIMIT 1
       ) a
  JOIN table b
    ON b.data1 = 1
   AND b.rating BETWEEN a.rating - 100 AND a.rating + 100
 ORDER
    BY RAND()
 LIMIT 1
;
```

The above will randomly select one record to be `a`, and then randomly select a record to be `b`. It therefore has many fewer records to order, and to join. This is less uniform, because it means that the likelihood of all choices of `a` will be equal, rather than being proportional to the number of possible corresponding choices of `b`, but maybe it is good enough for your purposes?

Comment: This has a chance to return no rows, even when there are ones that satisfy the original criteria.

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, absolutely. That's because the likelihood of all choices of `a` will be equal -- even choices of `a` that have no matching rows of `b`.